# Enable mute button even if screen is locked

Tags: 12.04, mute

Is it possible to make it enable that when I press mute button on my laptop it'll work even if screen is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gnome 3.6](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-lock-screen.html.en) can do that and, from what I can find, it's not implemented in Unity.

If you need that feature, upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 and use Gnome 3 as your desktop manager.